# How to pass XHTML a rel attr to jQuery function

Tags: jquery, function, xhtml, rel

I have a URL that holds a "rel" attribute that needs to be passed to a jQuery function.

Here is the URL:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/<?php echo $fblikeId; ?>" rel="<?php echo $fblikeId; ?>" ></a>
```

In a jQuery function I need to retrieve the value of the "rel" tag.

Here is the jQuery function:

```
jQuery(function($) {    
    $('#fblikes').advancedsocialstatus({
        'displayId':'fblikes',
        'service':'facebook',
        'countof':'likes',
        'userid': $(this).attr('rel'),
        'callback':'formatCount'
    });
});
```

The '`userid`' parameter of the above function needs to retrieve the value of the "`rel`" tag. This above function then passes all that data onto a higher jQuery function which works fine.

What is the best way to retrieve the "rel" attribute of the link? Have tried using "`$(this).attr('rel')`" but doesn't work.

The above function has multiple nodes. IE There may be multiple calls

```
jQuery(function($) { 
    $('#fblikes').advancedsocialstatus({
        'displayId':'fblikes',
        'service':'facebook',
        'countof':'likes',
        'userid':$(this).attr('rel'),
        'callback':'formatCount'
    });
    $('#fbtalks').advancedsocialstatus({
        'service':'facebook',
        'countof':'talks',
        'userid':'$(this).attr('rel')',
        'callback':'formatCount'
    });

});
```

Comment: where is id in your link above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `$(this)` arbitrarily in the options object of a plugin function. However you already know the element so there is no need for `this`; just use the same selector.

```
var $fblikes=$('#fblikes');

$fblikes.advancedsocialstatus({
        'displayId':'fblikes',
        'service':'facebook',
        'countof':'likes',
        'userid': $fblikes.attr('rel'),
        'callback':'formatCount'
});
```

This code assumes that `$('#fblikes')` is for the `<a>` tag shown but there is no `ID` in that html

Comment: Just updated the URL to contain the ID tag. Works an absolute treat. Thanks for the prompt response charliefl. Appreciate it.